# How to reproduce result of MATLAB `hist` function

Tags: c#, matlab, histogram

I have a MATLAB function that has this line code:

```
  hist(h.axesHistIBI,ibi(:,2),nBins); %plot
```

This line plots a histogram. Where h.axesHistIbi is:

[image: <code>h.axesHistIBI</code> details]

`ibi` is an array with 2 dimension and 400 elements. `nBins = 32`

This is the output:

[image: Resulting histogram]

Now I want to render the same chart but in a .NET web application. I have the save data (the same array, `nBins`). How can I display the same values?

Comment: If you have values saved, then what is the problem actually? Also is this a console app, winforms, or wpf? There are plenty of libraries for wpf and winforms to draw graphs

Comment: The problem is. HIST function group by the elements of array into a 32 column but I don't know in what mode do this

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the 32 bins chosen by `hist` can be obtained by saving the second output argument which [contains the value at the center of each bin](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html#btsgq3m-1-centers):

```
[~,centers] = hist(h.axesHistIBI,ibi(:,2),nBins);
```

You can then use your favorite .NET package to use the same bin centers to count the values in your .NET copy of `ibi` and render the resulting histogram.